# Auto Update html when form is change with ajax and Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I need to auto update an answer when form is changed. i can do it if i delete e.preventDefault(); but it cause refresh a page . i don't want it . is there any tricks to do this case ?

View Form1

```
<div>Some Content</div>
<div><?php echo($draft);?></div>
```

View Draft HTML

```
<p>This is array 1 : <?=$do->fill($keys[0]);?></p>
<p>This is array 2 : <?=$do->fill($keys[1]);?></p>
```

Ajax

```
$(function() {
    $(".auto_submit").change(function() {
        $("form").submit();
    });
});
$(function () {
    $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
        var url = $(location).attr('href');
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: url,
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function (e) {
                console.log($('form').serialize());
            }
        });
    });
});
```

View Form

```
<form class="auto_submit" action="<?=base_url('web/dashboard/create/html1');?>" method="post">
<input type="text" name="answer[]">
<input type="text" name="answer[]">
</form>
```

Controller CI

```
function create($doc){
        if(!isset($_POST['answer'])) $data['keys'] = null;
        else $data['keys'] = $_POST['answer'];
        $data['do'] = $this;
        if($doc == 'html1'){
            $data['draft'] = $this->load->view('doc/html1', $data, true);
            $this->template->admin_render('form/form1', $data);
        }
    }
```

Comment: use `location.reload()` at the `ajax success` like `success: function (e) {                console.log($('form').serialize()); location.reload();           }`

Comment: You are redirecting to  new page. if you dont want to refresh means you have to use the same page, i.e, `form1 and html1 content` should be in a same page

Comment: i used the same page . if i delete e.preventDefault(); it update a html with a refresh a page. but i don't want to refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to auto update without reload the whole page, just refresh a div,

```
<div id="div1">
<div id="div2">
<p>This is array 1 : <?=$do->fill($keys[0]);?></p>
<p>This is array 2 : <?=$do->fill($keys[1]);?></p>
</div>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$(function() {
    $(".auto_submit").change(function() {
        $("form").submit();
    });
});
$(function () {
    $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
        var url = $(location).attr('href');
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: url,
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function (e) {
                console.log($('form').serialize());
                $('#div1').load(url + ' #div2'); //note: the space before #div2 is very important
            }
        });
    });
});
```

update me if it helped.

**Edit:**
Then append your answer directly at the `<P>` tag without posting form

```
 <p>This is array 1 : <span id="answer1"><?=$do->fill($keys[0]);?></span></p>
    <p>This is array 2 : <span id="answer2"><?=$do->fill($keys[1]);?></span></p>
```

View Form:

```
<form class="auto_submit" action="<?=base_url('web/dashboard/create/html1');?>" method="post">
<input id="inputanswer1" type="text" name="answer[]">
<input id="inputanswer2" type="text" name="answer[]">
</form>
```

jquery:

```
 $(function() {
        $(".auto_submit").change(function() {
            //$("form").submit();
            var answer1 = $("#inputanswer1").val(),
                answer2 = $("#inputanswer2").val();
            $("#answer1").text(answer1);
            $("#answer2").text(answer2);
        });
    });
```

Comment: still not get the update from input form. in create function i just rendered the whole page.

Comment: yeah that do the tricks .. but i want to do it automatically without naming every input name and span with id . that's why i use name with array.

Comment: then you have to use database to store the posted values(temporarily), and use different function for form submit i.e, instead of `create` function use function like `update` which store the data into db, At `create` function fetch the data from the db. If you used this method means, then the div refresh will work perfectly